# Update data property / object in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

is there a way I can programmatically update the `data` object / property in vue.js? For example, when my component loads, my data object is:

```
data: function () {
    return {
        cars: true,
    }
}
```

And after an event is triggered, I want the `data` object to look like:

```
data: function () {
    return {
        cars: true,
        planes: true
    }
}
```

I tried:

```
<script>

module.exports = {

    data: function () {
        return {
            cars: true
        }
    },

    methods: {
        click_me: function () {
            this.set(this.planes, true);
        }
    },

    props: []

}

</script>
```

But this gives me the error `this.set is not a function`. Can someone help?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Vue does not allow dynamically adding new root-level reactive properties to an already created instance. However, it’s possible to add reactive properties to a nested object, So you may create an object and add a new property like that:

```
data: function () {
    return {
        someObject:{
            cars: true,
    }
}
```

and add the property with the [`vm.$set`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Objects) method:

```
methods: {
        click_me: function () {
            this.$set(this.someObject, 'planes', true)
        }
    }
```

for `vue 1.x` use `Vue.set(this.someObject, 'planes', true)`

[reactivity](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html)

Comment: Hi - I tried that but I keep getting `vue.common.js?e881:2964 Uncaught TypeError: exp.trim is not a function(…)`

Comment: @user1547174 this is looks vue 1.x try this `Vue.set(this.someObject, 'planes', true)`