# Replace Vue data() completely

Tags: vuejs2

I am looking for a way to replace the object under data.

```
  data() {
         return {
                form:{ .... }
                }
         }
```

I have learnt that I cannot directly change data itself so I moved all my variables under `form`. I want to replace all the data inside the `form` so that my form values are changed.

I have found a way to update single values like this;

`this.$set(this.someObject, 'planes', true)` where the solution is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40453427/update-data-property-object-in-vue-js) but I want to replace all the form object.

```
update_form(){
         let self = this
          $.ajax({
                 url: '/formdata/',
                 type: 'GET',
                  success: function(response){
               self.$set(self.form, needToUpdateAll)
                   }
               });
},
```

I am stuck right where it says `needToUpdateAll`. From the [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-set), it says `target, key, value`.
I am looking for a solution because I do not want to assign all values one by one (well the object has nested and nested objects :()

Any walk-around would be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not complicated. You don't need $set. Is `update_form()` in `methods`? If so, just do `this.form = response`. Top level names in your `data` are directly available in the rest of your Vue object.

Comment: This is great! Thank you @bbsimonbb. update_form() is under method, and it is being called under `created()`. In Vue panel (the Chrome extension) I can form is updated but in the screen I cannot see the changes:( thats why I am looking for a different solution.

Comment: My mistake :) JSON issue ~~ Thank you very much!