# How to do dynamic conditional rendering in loop vuejs ( v-if in v-for )

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a table component in a .vue file that and i'm trying to show some icons based on the dir of the order clicked

example:

```
<th v-for="(column, index) in columns" :key="index" @click="sort( index )">
                <span>{{ column.label }}
                    <i v-if="column.dir == 'desc'" class="fa fa-sort-down"></i>
                    <i v-else class="fa fa-sort-up"></i>
                </span>
```

The above is what the layout of the header is and my default column object looks like this:

```
data().....
  columns: [ 
            {
                label: '#',
                order: false,
                search: false,
                column: 'id',
                dir: 'desc'
            },
            {
                label: 'Username',
                order: true,
                search: true,
                column: 'username',
                dir: 'desc'
            }]
```

Now in my sort method, i update the clicked column

```
var col = this.columns[column];
col.dir = ( col.dir == 'desc' ) ? 'asc' : 'desc';


// I tried to no avail
this.$set(this.columns, index, col);

Vue.set(this.columns, index, col);

Also
this.$nextTick(function() {
  columns[index].dir = ( columns[index].dir == 'desc' ) ? 'asc' : 'desc';

});
```

if i check my Vue dev tool, i can see the value updated but the reactivity never gets back to the main columns object and the view isnt update to show the else portion.

Probably not grasping the concept firmly, any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

UPDATE.....

Thanks so much for the help, so i happens that font-awesome was removing the  from the DOM and replacing it with an SVG making it impossible for vue js to find it.

I will still choose an answer below nonetheless.

Comment: columns is an data?

Comment: @HamiltonGabriel yes it is

Comment: @MueyiwaMosesIkomi i think this post will help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40453427/update-data-property-object-in-vue-js

Comment: The problem is you're using `index` as key. Instead, use a unique identifier. Say `column`?

Comment: tried an approach like that @DJC , didnt work... i think it works for boolean but not for string. Thanks though

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu i won't say i haven't tried that.. with a different index. I mean the value updates in the console. But doesnt translate to the vue. If you can help with a fiddle or codepen, that will be great

Comment: I could, but you haven't provided enough info so I can create something without making assumptions. And that's not something I'm willing to do on SO. Providing a [mcve] is your part. Use codesandbox (or similar) if you find it difficult to wrap everything up into a SO snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I copied most of your code and it works fine for me... https://jsfiddle.net/aj2nf6cw/

Could it be because you wrote `var col = this.columns[column];` instead of `var col = this.columns[index];`?

Using var is fine because it will automatically refer to `this.columns[index]` because it's an object.

PS: I don't think you're using Vue.set properly. See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set. If you were to use it it would be `Vue.set(this.columns[index], 'dir', 'asc');`, but you don't have to use it because the your data is already reactive.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing doesn't work because you are creating a var inside the sort method that doesn't have the Vue observable like the this.columns. I leave you a [working code example here](https://codesandbox.io/embed/vue-template-eh0b2)

But basically you need to change this part in the sort method.

```
sort(index){
   this.columns[index].dir = (this.columns[index].dir == 'desc') ? 'asc' : 'desc'; 
}
```

Comment: I put that button there just for testing purposes.

Comment: I had tried something of the sort. The value of that index changes alright as with my other attempts... the ui doesnt if. if its asc it should show the v-else but it doesnt. Reactivity doesnt stull happen @Jalil. Can you add the click to the th itself. Thanks

Comment: Tell me if it worked or not, if it worked, please mark the answer as good to let other people see it too. if not, tell me c;

Comment: @sure will... I noticed something strange tho... if it do {{ column.dir }}, the value changes. but it doesnt work with the v-if. Weird

Comment: In my font-awesome removes the <i></i> from the dom and replaces it with an svg... so vue js can't find it

Comment: For that you can.
1. Wrap it in a div with the v-if or.
2. Use the font awsome vue component

Comment: Yes @Jalil that's what i did eventually (Vue Component), thanks for help and time