# How can we declare a variable dynamically in data function in vue js?

Tags: javascript, forms, vue.js

I have a `form` with three `input` fields `name`, `email` and `phone` but I want the user to be able to add more `input` fields dynamically so for every new input field added to the form, I want to declare a variable in the `form` object of `data` function.

The `data()` function is as below:

```
data(){
    return{
        form:{
            name:'',
            email:'',
            phone: '',
        }
    }
}
```

Here as you can see I have three variables in the `form` object but I want to dynamically add another variable like `phone2`, `phone3`...etc. whenever a new input field is added dynamically to the form.

Any help is appreciated in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40455420/2185093

Answer (score 0):

for your question is the full answer by @Dan. But why are you don't want to create a phone array to store dynamic phones in it? You can easily work with array add\remove and etc...

```
data(){
return{
    form:{
        name:'',
        email:'',
        phone: [XXXXXXX, XXXXXX],
    }
}
```

}